# Regarding the extension of source code

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Once I create the project,I found my source code was named as "myfilename.xcodeproj". Whether ".xcodeproj" is extension or else it has some other extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is indeed the extension. In Finder, press CMD-I to see file info, including its full name and the option to show/hide the extension. 
However, it is not your source code, that is stored in .m, .h, ... files. The xcodeproj file is your project, that links the source files, build settings, etc...

Comment: Pre-compiled header (speeds up the building, I think)

Comment: @icoder: The contents of ".pch" files get automagically imported in every single ".m/.c" file of your project. Think of them as some kind of project-wide omnipresent header files.